# WebLogic multiple Connections

Tags: java, web, connection, database-connection, weblogic12c

I have two DataSources on my **WebLogic Server**, each accessing different DBs.
On my client application, I have some methods that need to connect to the *first* DB, and others that need to connect to the *second* one. 
 But when I run it, it's only getting the connection of the first method I execute. 
For example, if I execute a method that gets the connection of the firs DB, **only the methods that access this DB will work**, I can't execute any method that needs the other connection. 
Can somebody help me with this? I'm using WebLogic 12c
This is my class that get the Data Sources:

```
package com.henrique.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class KironMySql {

    private static DataSource KironMySql = null;
    private static Context context = null;

    public static DataSource KironMySqlConn() throws Exception{
        if (KironMySql != null) {
            return KironMySql;
        }
        try{
            if(KironMySql == null){
                context = new InitialContext();
                KironMySql = (DataSource) context.lookup("KironLocal");
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return KironMySql;
    }

    public static DataSource KironMySqlConnIp() throws Exception{
        if (KironMySql != null) {
            return KironMySql;
        }
        try{
            if(KironMySql == null){
                context = new InitialContext();
                KironMySql = (DataSource) context.lookup("KironTabelaApp");
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return KironMySql;
    }

    public static Connection KironConnection(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = KironMySqlConn().getConnection();
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static Connection KironConnectionIp(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = KironMySqlConnIp().getConnection();
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

And here are two examples of methods that use different connections:

```
public JSONArray Login(String usu_login, String usu_senha) throws Exception{
        PreparedStatement query = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ToJson converter = new ToJson();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

        try{
            conn = KironMySql.KironConnection();
            query = conn.prepareStatement("select usu_nome from usuario where usu_login = ? and usu_senha = ?");
            query.setString(1, usu_login);
            query.setString(2, usu_senha);
            ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
            json = converter.toJSONArray(rs);
            query.close();          
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return json;
        }finally{
            if(conn != null) conn.close();
        }
        return json;
    }

    public JSONArray getIp(String emp_codigo) throws Exception{
        PreparedStatement query = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ToJson converter = new ToJson();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

        try{
            conn = KironMySql.KironConnectionIp();
            query = conn.prepareStatement("select con_ip from conexaoapp where emp_codigo = ?");
            query.setString(1, emp_codigo);
            ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
            json = converter.toJSONArray(rs);
            query.close();          
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return json;
        }finally{
            if(conn != null) conn.close();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified from "monitoring" tab in WL that both your data sources are in "running" state ??

Comment: @hagrawal There's only one connection running. How can I change both connections to running state

Comment: But what about "KironLocal" and "KironTabelaApp" DS in WL, are they both running or not ??

Comment: If you want different connections with different databases, then you need to have different data sources for each database. And from application, get the connection with each DS (which means connection with database), and use it. Do not use same connection to connect with 2 different DS (which means connection with database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the case you are using `private static DataSource KironMySql = null;` instance. Have separate `DataSource` object for different DS.

Essentially you were masking `KironLocal` DS when trying to get `KironTabelaApp` DS connection.

So, your updated code will look like as below:

```
package com.henrique.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class KironMySql {

    private static DataSource KironMySql = null;
    private static DataSource KironMySqlIp = null;  //This is new line for code fix, and using "KironMySqlIp" instance later in the code where connection with "KironTabelaApp" data source is needed.
    private static Context context = null;

    public static DataSource KironMySqlConn() throws Exception{
        if (KironMySql != null) {
            return KironMySql;
        }
        try{
            if(KironMySql == null){
                context = new InitialContext();
                KironMySql = (DataSource) context.lookup("KironLocal");
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return KironMySql;
    }

    public static DataSource KironMySqlConnIp() throws Exception{
        if (KironMySqlIp != null) {
            return KironMySqlIp;
        }
        try{
            if(KironMySqlIp == null){
                context = new InitialContext();
                KironMySqlIp = (DataSource) context.lookup("KironTabelaApp");
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return KironMySqlIp;
    }

    public static Connection KironConnection(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = KironMySqlConn().getConnection();
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static Connection KironConnectionIp(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = KironMySqlConnIp().getConnection();
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want different connections with different databases, then you need to have different data sources for each database. And from application, get the connection with each DS (which means connection with database), and use it. Do not use same connection to connect with 2 different DS (which means connection with database)

Comment: It didn't work.. I thoght it could be that, but I still have only one Data Source Running in WL

Comment: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'KironTabelaApp'. The DBMS driver exception was: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`Error weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'KironTabelaApp'. The DBMS driver exception was: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Comment: 'm getting this exception

Comment: This is because in your WL "KironTabelaApp" data source is not running. You need to go to monitoring tab and verify that "KironTabelaApp" and "KironLocal" are in running state ..

Comment: First you need to resolve your WL issue, then it will come to application code .. Until your WL has 2 required DS running, nothing will move forward ..

Comment: Only KironLocal is in Running State.. How can I put both running?

Comment: Do you have other DS configured in your WL ?? If so, have you started it ?? Could you please provide - WL's DS screen shot and WL's DS monitoring tab screen shot ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83356/discussion-between-henrique-romao-and-hagrawal).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Data Sources]

[image]

Here's my Data Sources and the Monitoring tab

Comment: This is it. I told right that your second DS may not be running. So, now click on the "KironTabelaApp" data source .. Go to control tab and then select the data source, and start it. Basically you need to start "KironTabelaApp" DS. Once done, again go to data source -> monitoring tab and verify that both DS are up and running ..